# Google Analytics SDK for iOS Crash

Tags: ios, crash, google-analytics, crash-reports

I get the following crash (0x8badf00d) because of something to do with Google Analytics SDK 1.1. What's also strange is that iOS killed it in just 1 second?

I initialize the tracker like this:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kGANWebPropertyID dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec delegate:self];
```

Here is the crash log

```
Incident Identifier: 5459E916-5306-408A-A630-F405DFD97711
CrashReporter Key:   20ac546c31144c5f86de428ce3332012ab604d49
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         XXXX [63]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2AADFD36-5C6F-4EEC-B740-0DE77C6FE2A9/XXXX.app/XXXX
Identifier:      XXXX
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-07-04 17:23:33.464 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
XXXX failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.060 (user 0.480, system 0.580), 11% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.050, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   CFNetwork                       0x34cb6b66 SocketStream::read(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 274
7   CFNetwork                       0x34cb6a46 virtual thunk to SocketStream::read(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 30
8   CFNetwork                       0x34cb7a5c ReadStreamCallbacks::_read(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*, void*) + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x308ffcf4 CFReadStreamRead + 268
10  XXXX                            0x000d2992 -[GANTCPSocket read:length:] (GANTCPSocket.m:99)
11  XXXX                            0x000d703c -[GANDataDispatcher socketBecameReadable:] (GANDataDispatcher.m:413)
12  XXXX                            0x000d2936 ReadStreamCallBack (GANTCPSocket.m:44)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x308ffa1a _signalEventSync + 70
14  CoreFoundation                  0x308ff9b6 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 58
15  CoreFoundation                  0x308ff8aa _CFStreamSignalEvent + 326
16  CoreFoundation                  0x308ff75c CFReadStreamSignalEvent + 4
17  CFNetwork                       0x34cb4c14 SocketStream::dispatchSignalFromSocketCallbackUnlocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder*) + 20
18  CFNetwork                       0x34c423f4 SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 104
19  CFNetwork                       0x34c42376 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 42
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3095c48a __CFSocketDoCallback + 334
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3095d4a2 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 78
22  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3095969c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 188
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
25  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
26  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
27  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
28  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
29  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
30  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
31  XXXX                            0x000026b2 main (main.m:22)
32  XXXX                            0x00002594 0x1000 + 5524

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
    3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 2 name:  WebThread
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f5327e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x341dd7f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fc60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3095d8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   MapKit                          0x33976456 TileCachePrivate::runCacheThread() + 274
7   MapKit                          0x3397633a _runCacheThread(void*) + 2
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  CADispatch worker
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fd18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3568d860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35634eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   QuartzCore                      0x34421730 CA::DispatchGroup::thread(void*) + 84
4   QuartzCore                      0x3443b836 thread_fun + 10
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   MapKit                          0x3398120e +[NSThread(MKAdditions) _mapkit_runThread:] + 334
7   Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: place answer, if you found any...so that other can get help...

Answer (score 0):

My adhoc with GANTracker crash on iPodTouch 4Gen running iOS6, but same build run fine on iPad3 and iPodTouch with retina4"

additional debugger info, for future reference.

With Zombie on :::

> 2013-01-03 11:16:19.909 Car[2502:907] *** -[GANTCPSocket close]:
>   message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d3fbbf0

Backtrace :::

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x3874d468 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 192, stop reason = trace
    frame #0: 0x3874d468 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 192
    frame #1: 0x386a4f68 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 24
    frame #2: 0x0035591e Car`-[GANTCPSocket connect:port:inLine:] + 294 at GANTCPSocket.m:102
    frame #3: 0x0034f6f6 Car`-[GANDataDispatcher dispatchPendingHits] + 134 at GANDataDispatcher.m:233
    frame #4: 0x0034fb76 Car`-[GANDataDispatcher dispatchHits:] + 278 at GANDataDispatcher.m:135
    frame #5: 0x003565e4 Car`-[GANTracker dispatch:withTimeout:] + 264 at GANTracker.m:392
    frame #6: 0x003573e4 Car`-[GANTracker dispatch] + 144 at GANTracker.m:413
    frame #7: 0x00355dae Car`-[GANTracker dispatch:] + 14 at GANTracker.m:499
    ...snipped...
```